# Connect Radeon R9 290X DirectCU 2 to Corsair HX850

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply

I have received a new graphics card after my old one died after a couple of weeks
The card is a [Radeon R9 290X DirectCU 2](http://www.guru3d.com/articles-pages/asus-radeon-r9-290x-directcuii-oc-review,3.html) and i wish to install it

I got a single wire with it; one side has 8 pins and the other side is split into two connectors one with 6 pins and the other with 5 pins. My power supply is a [Corsair HX850](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0090I9W66).

A have a couple of questions i was hoping you guys could help me with

1. Which connector goes into which slot. So for example is the two headed side supposed to connected to the graphics card or the power unit
2. The power unit doesn't seem to accept either of the three connectors
3. It also appears that if i get past hurdle 1 and 2 that the wire is too short. However i have another wire that came with the computer which is long enough but has 6 pins on one side and 8 pins on the other. It fits into the graphics card and the power unit without issue but obviously i don't want to burn anything out

If the cable i have is unsuitable for the power unit that came with the graphics card and the backup cable i have is no use can anyone recommend the correct cable

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HX850 model is very modular.
You'll need to connect two of the PCI-e power cables between the power supply and your graphics card for it to function properly. Don't connect any less!
These modular cables should've come in the package with your power supply unit.

- Plug the 8-pin blue connector of both cables into any of the blue connectors on the power supply unit.
- Take one of the 6+2 pin black connectors and plug it into the 8-pin receptacle on your graphics card.
- Take the other black connector and split them in a 6 and 2 pin connector (they can be coupled/uncoupled).
- Ignore the 2 pins and plug the remaining 6-pin connector into the 6-pin receptacle on the graphics card.

If it doesn't fit, it's not the correct cable/connector/orientation.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i was looking for. It looks like i will have to buy the cables off the internet as my cables are only 6 pin on one side and 8 pin on the other. If you could recommend a site, i would be very appreciative.